# freeing an SDL_Surface correctly?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

Can i free my SDL_Surface* surf by doing this:

```
    SDL_Surface* surf;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(foofont, foostring, foocolor);
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    surf = NULL;
```

Or does this cause memory leaks?

Comment: You can see [here](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_51.html) that this is exactly what the documentation recommends.

Comment: @BoBTFish negative, the documentation explicitly frees *each* (the only one) surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: Based on how I understand the documentation, that will cause a leak.
Seeing as you are basically calling the function 5 times, where it creates a new surface each time. Ie, you need to free all the surfaces each time.
so

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(foofont, foostring, foocolor);
    SDL_FreSurface(surf)
}
surf = NULL;
```

You can read the documentation here:

https://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf_44.html

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FreeSurface

Comment: So it doesn't make 3 new surfaces and only frees one?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I think that will cause a leak yeah, was a bit quick on the trigger. Have edited the response now.